# drupal 6 search returns blank page

Tags: search, drupal

I run a Drupal 6 website www.immigrantguide.ca.  I created a test site for it at www.test.immigrantguide.ca). The site includes the module "Search 6.28".

The site uses a custom theme and when you try to do a keyword search, the search simply returns a blank page. The admin backend uses the Garland theme and when you do a site search in Garland it returns results. Since the search function doesn't work I removed it from the main site but left it up on the test site so I could try to figure out how to make it work.

Comment: First, confirm you have some content added to your site. Second, run the cron for few times and they give the search a try.

Comment: tried that but no luck. thanks anyway.

Comment: A completely blank page? If so, are you sure there's not a PHP error in your theme? Is your php.ini configured to show errors rather than a blank page?

Comment: hi  - yup, it's completely blank. There may well be an error in the theme. Unfortunately it's custom and I didn't write it. So I'm not exactly sure what I'm even looking for. I'm no PHP expert, but I'll check the php.ini and see if I can see anything. thanks.

Comment: Did you check the apache logs? And Drupal logs?

Comment: OK problem solved: the template.php file had an extra "?>" in it that it should not have had. Got rid of it and now all is well. Thanks for the help.